# Inputting Only Alphabetical Input - Slick2D

Tags: java, slick

I'm trying to obtain the user input for when they enter their own name. However I would prefer to have it Alphabetically.

This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)) {

    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_B)) {

    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_C)) {

    }
    //continued for each letter.
```

Is there an easier way to obtain the input? An hopefully make sure its only alphabetical?

Comment: i only develop games in c# and c++, so i can't post this as a real answer as it might be an inefficient solution: make a keylistener, and on the keypress/keydown event, check with .getKeyChar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java `Character` class has a simple [`isLetter` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29).

The easiest way to handle key presses is to create a class that implements the [`KeyListener` class](http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/KeyListener.html). A little example would be:

```
public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {

     @Override
     public void keyPressed(int key, char c) {
         if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
             //do letter stuff

         } else {
             //do other stuff
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void keyReleased(int key, char c) {
         //do released key stuff
     }
}
```

Create an instance of `MyKeyListener` and then use `input.addKeyListener(myKeyListenerInstance)` to add the listener to your input.

Answer (score 0):

Make an input handler class which stores the result of your key strokes then filter what you need using a regex.

A simple `[a-zA-Z]` will do the job.

Edit: You make a method which you call each tick that stores the current keys as an array

```
public List<char> pollInput() {
    List<char> keys = new ArrayList<char>;
    while (Keyboard.next()) {
        keys.add((char)Keyboard.getEventKey());
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Then you convert the list to an array and to a string which you pass through a  regex. (Sorry i'm typing on a phone so i'm doing this all from memory).

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: Alex' idea is essentially adding whatever the player typed to your name (temporary). Once that's done, you can use a regular expression to match (and remove) all characters not fitting your filter. The following line should do the trick, although this is Javascript, but I guess it would work in Java as well: `name.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/, '');` (assuming `name` is the name stored as a string)